# Improve memory usage of Vert.x sever

Tags: java, memory, vert.x

I have a *Vert.x* web server which provides Websocket service. *Vert.x* server sends some data to client when client registers on server then the client sends a ACK back to server to make sure those data has already been delivered reliably.

I found the *Vert.x* server consumes a lot of memory after it has finished all the work.

Below  are steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Config *JVM* parameter before starting our test:

   - Open /vert.x-2.02-final/bin/
   - Modify value of JVM_OPTS from "" to "-Xms128M -Xmx128M"
   - Save and exitModify *serverIpAddress* to your server ip address in `VertXSocketClient`
2. Client will register to *1180* websocket channel on the *Vert.x* server.
   You can get code here:
   https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptenlx78iin8dmj/VertXSocketClient.java
3. run *testserver* with command `vertx run testserver.java`

The memory usage of *Vert.x*server will be printed out in your console with format:

*total memory - free memory = used memory(MB)*

```
System.gc()    
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
int mb = 1024 * 1024;
totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory() / mb;
freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory() / mb;
```

I call `System.gc()` every 5 secs to make sure to free memory. Yes, I know. `System.gc()` shouldn't be called frequently. It has negative impact to system performance. The used memory does not decrease without such an instruction.

You can download the code here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6oxtfhgwffed72c/AAAX-BvYdGaTBgnRagxD9Bf-a/TestServer.java

4. run *VertXSocketClient* with command `vertx run VertXSocketClient.java`

The client will register to websocket channel server automatically and the server instance will send data to client after registration has finished.

Here down the sample code to send data to client:

```
byte[] serverResponseData = serverResponse.getBytes();
Buffer buffer= new Buffer(serverResponseData);  
ws.write(buffer);
```

With above code, used memory would be up to *62MB* after all work is done, wherease it is only up to *15MB* if I comment out `ws.write(buffer)`.

My assumption is that *Vert.x* server always sets aside *62MB* of memory for its lifetime.Isn't it supposed to release memory after the work is done?

Comment: Hi there. What exactly are you looking for? Vert.x, or more specific the VM cannot know when work is done, and if action starts and many e.g. threads are created, objects build for connections to handle etc. it of course stays prepared and caches in some occurrences these. I haven't looked into the insights of your example or Vert.x directly, but having threadpools alone etc. are all the things that fire up after your first actions, listening and waiting for more. Some will later be removed, some never because they stay waiting.

Comment: Your total JVM process size is 15Mb? that seems unlikely...
As does the possibility of it being 15Mb only of heap.

Comment: You seem to not be closing the WebSocket connection at any point, so it would stay open and available. That probably explains the memory usage you're seeing. The increased memory usage from the `ws.write` call is probably due to an increased buffer size after the write in order to accommodate future writes, though that's just a guess. I will say though that I don't really find those numbers particularly high, so I'm not sure why you're worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check Hazelcast `map` configuration if you are using Vert.x. Maybe it's not related to your problem and your Vert.x usage, but I had similar problems with memory usage and found that my configuration (in `cluster.xml`) was not appropriate regarding my use cases.

Some points you should check in Hazelcast config:

- `backup-count` - By default, Hazelcast has one sync backup copy
- `time-to-live-seconds` - Maximum time in seconds for each map entry to stay in the map is 0 (`infinite`) by default
- `max-idle-seconds` - Maximum time in seconds for each entry to stay idle in the map is 0 (`infinite`) by default
- `eviction-policy` - `NONE` eviction policy for Maps is used by default

See [Hazelcast Map documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#map) for more details.